# Adding a New Column with an Increment in R

Tags: r

I am trying to add a new column to the beginning of my data frame in R. Right now I have something that looks like

```
a b c d
1 2 3 4
1 2 3 4
4 1 6 3
```

and I want to add a new column, z, that adds by 5 in each row to get something like

```
z a b c d
5 1 2 3 4
10 1 2 3 4
15 4 1 6 3
```

Answer (score 5):

Try

```
z<- seq(5, length.out=nrow(df1), by=5)
```

Or

```
z <- 5*seq_len(nrow(df1))
cbind(z, df1)
#   z a b c d
#1  5 1 2 3 4
#2 10 1 2 3 4
#3 15 4 1 6 3
```

Answer (score 2):

declare your new z vector by say `z <- c(5,10,15)` or using another way if it follows a particular pattern. After initialization use the `cbind` function to merge it with the original dataframe.

`cbind(df,z)` adds the new vector at the end and `cbind(z,df)` adds in the beginning. since u want it at the beginning u can use `cbind(z,df)`